# SwiftUI delegate

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a new application, I am new to programming with iOS.

I have a question before, I worked with Swift and UIKit.

Now I want to pass my code to SwiftUI, the question is where do I declare my delegate for a library.

example of my previous code

```
import UIKit
var myCentralManager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
let user: HealthUser = HealthUser()
var device: TS28B = TS28B()
var controllerTS28B: TS28BController = TS28BController()
var connectedDevice: TS28B?

class WalkthroughContentViewController: UIViewController, TS28BControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var headingLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var subHeadingLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            subHeadingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView!
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var index = 0
    var heading = ""
    var subHeading = ""
    var imageFile = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        headingLabel.text = heading
        subHeadingLabel.text = subHeading
        contentImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFile)
        controllerTS28B = TS28BController.shared()
        print("ENTRA EN StartDiscoverTS28B")
        controllerTS28B.delegate = self
        controllerTS28B.startScan().self
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
    
    // MARK: - delegate

    func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDiscoverDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("The agent of the device is found")
        connectedDevice = device

        controller?.connectDevice(connectedDevice)

        if let device = device {
            print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectSuccessDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Successfully connected agent")
        connectedDevice = device
        if let device = device {
            print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectFailDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Proxy failed to connect")
        //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接失败";
    }

    func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDisconnectDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Disconnected proxy")
        //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接断开";

        if let device = device {
            print("DisConnectDevice: \(device) ")
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, device: TS28B?, didUpdateTemperature value: Float, temperatureUnit unit: TemperatureUnit, measure date: Date?, measureLocation type: TemperatureType) {
        print("Temperature UNIDAD:", unit)
        print("Temperature:", value)
    }
}
```

para swiftui me sale esto

[image]

I have no idea where to declare TS28BControllerDelegate

este es mi nuevo codigo

```
//
//  TakeTemperatureTS28BUIView.swift
//  aidicarev3UI
//
//  Created by Laura Ramirez on 26/08/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

var myCentralManager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
let user: HealthUser = HealthUser()
var device: TS28B = TS28B()
var controllerTS28B: TS28BController = TS28BController()
var connectedDevice: TS28B?

struct TakeTemperatureTS28BUIView: View {
    @State private var index = 1
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    
    init(){
        Theme.navigationBarColors(background: .white , titleColor: UIColor( red: CGFloat(92/255.0), green: CGFloat(203/255.0), blue: CGFloat(207/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0)))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    VStack(){
                        Text("s2Tittle")
                            .modifier(Fonts(fontName: .bold, size: 9))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("blackColor"))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .padding(.top,10)
                            .padding(.leading,10)
                            .padding(.trailing,10)
                        Image("logo")
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5, height: 40.0)
                            .padding()
                        
                        Text("s3Tittle")
                            .modifier(Fonts(fontName: .medium, size: 9))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("grayDarkColor"))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .padding(.top,1)
                            .padding(.bottom,10)
                    }
                    .background(Color("whiteColor"))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                    Button(action:{
                       Sincroniza()
                    }){
                        Text("Conectar")
                            .modifier(Fonts(fontName: .bold, size: 10))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("blueColor"))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .offset(y: -20)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
                .padding()
                .padding()
                Spacer()
                MenuMain(index: self.$index)
            }
            .background(Color("backgroundColor"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar { // <2>
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { // <3>
                    VStack {
                        Text("s1Tittle").font(.headline)
                            .modifier(Fonts(fontName: .light, size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("grayDarkColor"))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                Sincroniza()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                //desconectar dispositivos
            }
        }
    
}

struct TakeTemperatureTS28BUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TakeTemperatureTS28BUIView()
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .accentColor(.black)
            .toolbar { // <2>
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { // <3>
                    HStack {
                        Text("s1Tittle").font(.headline)
                            .modifier(Fonts(fontName: .light, size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("grayDarkColor"))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func iHealthAuth() {
    print("ENTRA EN AUTENTIFICACION DE IHEALTH TS28B")
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "com_aidicare_aidicarev3UI_ios", ofType: ".pem")
    let cert = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
    print(cert as Any)
    
    IHSDKCloudUser.commandGetSDKUserInstance().commandSDKUserValidation(withLicense: cert as Data?, userDeviceAccess: {
        devices in
        print("--devices--")
        print(devices as Any)
    }, userValidationSuccess: { UserAuthenResult in
        print("--UserAuthenResult--")
        print(UserAuthenResult)
        StartDiscoverTS28B()
    }, disposeErrorBlock: { UserAuthenResult in
        print("--UserAuthenResult--")
        print(UserAuthenResult)
        switch (UserAuthenResult) {
            case UserAuthen_InputError:
                print("error")
                break;
            case UserAuthen_CertificateExpired:
                print("certiificado expirado")
                break;
            case UserAuthen_InvalidCertificate:
                print("certificado no valido")
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    })
}

func Sincroniza(){
    print("ENTRA EN TOMA DE TEMPERATURA TS28B")
    iHealthAuth()
}

func StartDiscoverTS28B(){
    controllerTS28B = TS28BController.shared()
    print("ENTRA EN StartDiscoverTS28B")
    controllerTS28B = self
    controllerTS28B.startScan().self
}


// MARK: - delegate

func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDiscoverDevice device: TS28B?) {
    print("The agent of the device is found")
    connectedDevice = device

    controller?.connectDevice(connectedDevice)

    if let device = device {
        print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectSuccessDevice device: TS28B?) {
    print("Successfully connected agent")
    connectedDevice = device
    if let device = device {
        print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectFailDevice device: TS28B?) {
    print("Proxy failed to connect")
    //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接失败";
}

func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDisconnectDevice device: TS28B?) {
    print("Disconnected proxy")
    //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接断开";

    if let device = device {
        print("DisConnectDevice: \(device) ")
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, device: TS28B?, didUpdateTemperature value: Float, temperatureUnit unit: TemperatureUnit, measure date: Date?, measureLocation type: TemperatureType) {
    print("Temperature UNIDAD:", unit)
    print("Temperature:", value)
}
```

Comment: First of all declaring global properties outside of any class or struct is very bad practice. Secondly in a storyboard environment `TS28BController()` creates a brand new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. And `DispatchGroup` inside a SwiftUI view makes no sense.

Comment: could you help me with this **TS28BController() creates a brand new instance which is not the instance in the storyboard.**? @vadian

Comment: probably you should create an observableobject class that conforms to your delegate that you need (in your case it's `TS28BControllerDelegate`) and use it inside the view as a `@StateObject`

Comment: In general, what you previously did in viewDidLoad should now be done in the init and/or .onAppear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is English only please translate your post. You may consider also joining [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a class with the delegate that is needed

```
let delegate = ts28bControllerDelegate.init()
delegate.StartSync()
```

example:

```
class ts28bControllerDelegate: NSObject, TS28BControllerDelegate {
    var myCentralManager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var controllerTS28B: TS28BController = TS28BController()
    let user: HealthUser = HealthUser()
    var device: TS28B = TS28B()
    var connectedDevice: TS28B?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("ENTRA EN StartDiscoverTS28B")
        controllerTS28B = TS28BController.shared()
        controllerTS28B.delegate = self
    }
    
    func StartSync(){
        print("empieza StartSync")
        controllerTS28B.startScan()
    }
    
    // MARK: - delegate

    public func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDiscoverDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("The agent of the device is found")
        connectedDevice = device

        controller?.connectDevice(connectedDevice)

        if let device = device {
            print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
        }
    }

    public func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectSuccessDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Successfully connected agent")
        connectedDevice = device
        if let device = device {
            print("DiscoverDevice: \(device)")
        }
    }

    public func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didConnectFailDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Proxy failed to connect")
        //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接失败";
    }

    public func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, didDisconnectDevice device: TS28B?) {
        print("Disconnected proxy")
        //    self.recordTextView.text = @"连接断开";

        if let device = device {
            print("DisConnectDevice: \(device) ")
        }
    }

    public func controller(_ controller: TS28BController?, device: TS28B?, didUpdateTemperature value: Float, temperatureUnit unit: TemperatureUnit, measure date: Date?, measureLocation type: TemperatureType) {
        print("Temperature UNIDAD:", unit)
        print("Temperature:", value)
    }


}
```

I think it was very obvious but understanding the steps when you are new sometimes costs

thanks!